# Remove responsive feature with Dash plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm on google colab with MacOS 11.5.2.
Dash version I'm using is 1.21.0

I'm usually write dash code in bigger screen, and now I'm notice this issue when move to smaller screen. Here's a the example :

```py
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = JupyterDash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
                       dbc.Row([dbc.Col("Top left"),dbc.Col("Top right")]),
                       dbc.Row([dbc.Col("Bottom left"),dbc.Col("Bottom right")])
                       ]
    )                      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

And the output is as expected, 2 x 2 grid with each word in respective position.
But when I'm replacing the text with plot, the grid structure changed automatically.

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
df = px.data.tips()
fig1 = px.histogram(df,x="tip")
fig2 = px.scatter(df,x="total_bill",y="tip")
fig3 = px.bar(df,x="sex")
fig4 = px.histogram(df,x="total_bill")

app.layout = html.Div([
                       dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig1,id="Histogram tip")),dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig2,id="Scatter plot bill vs tip"))]),
                       dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig3,id="Barplot gender "),width=3),dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig4,id="Histogram bill"),width=9)])
                       ]
    )                   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Now the first row become stacked vertically instead of horizontally stacked. Here's the screenshot (I zoom out a bit)

[image]

But if i really zoom out my browser that far, the displayed layout is correctly appear

[image]

I don't understand why the responsive layout feature kicks in this scenario and I want to turn it off so my dashboard appear in 2x2 instead of 3 rows layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve it by using `dbc.Container` to my app and set `fluid=False`.

Comment: Hi Vinson, what is the adjusted code? What did you replace by dbc.Container?

Comment: its been so long and i barely remember. but I think we put the entire html.div inside a dbc.Container